# Getting error "Cannot load module 'MapKit' as 'MapKit'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, mapkit

This is my first program. And, I am implementing *MapKit*. The following is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

If I am not importing MapKit, I get an error as 'weak may be only applied to class and class-bound protocol type'.
And if I do, then I get the error mentioned in the title.

I do not understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: what is your project Name

Comment: MapKitImplementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Reason : You are using framework name as for your project name, which can't be same at all. And, it is causing conflicts. Just modify your **Project Name** and try again. It'll surely work.